# How to get different samples based on a sample size

Tags: r, sample

I have a sample like this:

```html
V   echo
A   2
D   4
N   12
P   6
D   4
P   2
N   3
A   1
```

I want to get three data frame samples (n=20,n=50, n=100), based on this sample with replacement and then I want to calculate the mean and SD for each sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over those numbers

```
sapply(c(20, 50, 100), function(x) {
     x1 <- sample(df1$echo, x, replace = TRUE)
     c(Mean = mean(x1), SD = sd(x1))})
```

---

If we want to return 3 dataset samples

```
lst1 <- lapply(c(20, 50, 100), function(x) {
            i1 <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df1)), x, replace = TRUE)
            df1[i1, , drop = FALSE]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not give me three data frame samples

Comment: @Rose I read your question as to get the `mean` and `SD` for each sample.  The code `sample` the 'echo' base don the number looped, and get the `mean` and `sd` of that column

Comment: Superb! Thank you+1

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like below?

```
n <- c(20, 50, 100)
lapply(
    n,
    function(k) {
        df[sample(nrow(df), k, replace = TRUE), ]
    }
)
```

Or, we can use `split` (probably faster than my previous option)

```
split(
    df[sample(nrow(df), sum(n), replace = TRUE), ],
    rep(seq_along(n), n)
)
```

Comment: @Rose You are welcome. I updated with another option using `split`, which might be faster.